# Quicktime shows "The operation could not be completed" when trying to record a movie on macOS

Tags: error, quicktime, monterey

When I go to File > New Movie Recording

[image]

I see the following error message

[image: The operation could not be completed]

I tried to remove some caches and preferences from Library folder, but didn't fix the issue.

Any other ideas are appreciated.

Using MacOs Monterey (12.2.1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a problem related to [Krisp](https://krisp.ai) camera, a software I use to reduce audio noise and now has a feature to modify backgrounds by adding a virtual camera device.

When selecting that device for the first time, crashed Quicktime player.

## Solution

1. Quit Quicktime
2. Remove `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX.plist` and `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX/Data/Library/Saved Application State/*`
3. Quit Krisp
4. Reopen Quicktime and try to do a Movie record again. It will show a static image saying Krisp Camera is not available. At this point, select another camera source.

Done.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem recently, however, I'm not using "Krisp". For me the problem was related to an iPhone, I tried to use as a camera before but wasn't able to connect to due to company restrictions. So QuickTime just tried to connect again each time and failed with the above error.
I think this problem is generally caused when QuickTime tries to connect to a camera source that is not available (anymore).

**Solution (based on [Ricardo Martins solution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/437001/145437))**

1. Quit QuickTime
2. Remove `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX.plist` and `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX/Data/Library/Saved Application State/*`
3. Disconnect your iPhone from your MacBook and put it into Flight Mode.
4. Reopen Quicktime and try to do a Movie record again. It will start successfully and just use the MacBook camera.

Done.